# Error in python numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to run a script which is written below. The focus is to print 'rab'.

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate


x = [64, 67, 70.459, 73, 76]
y = [0.697, 0.693, 0.694, 0.698, 0.702]
z = [0.748, 0.745, 0.747, 0.757, 0.763]


delT = 1

f = open('volume-temperature.dat', 'r')
V = []
for line in f:
        parts = line.split()
        if len(parts) > 1:
                #print parts[1]
                V.append(parts[1])
f.close()

for M in range(0,5):
        T = 0+M*delT
        if M == 0:
            rab = np.interp(V[M], x, y)
            print rab
        else:
            print M
```

The problem is while printing 'rab' I am geting this error:

```
return compiled_interp(x, xp, fp, left, right)
ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array
```

It looks some fundamental error, But as I am new in Python, so a little help would be appreciated. N.B. V[M] for M = 0 is 70.31

Comment: Aside: Since you're new I'll give you an important warning: don't use star imports like `from numpy import *`.  While it can be convenient sometimes it replaces certain built-in functions like `sum` with numpy's versions which behave very differently (i.e. can give the opposite results) in some circumstances.

Comment: I would add to DSM not to import it twice use either `from numpy import *` or `import numpya as np`

Comment: I tried with your suggestions, but problem remains same.

Comment: If I just put the 70.31 instead of V[M], then it is working. But since I have a series of values so, in any case I have to use V[M].

Comment: @TanmoyChakraborty what happens when you print V[M] after you loop through the file? Also, I would advise learning how to use the ["with as"](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) file iterator, because it's much easier and cleaner :-) (the info in the link is towards the bottom of that section)

Comment: @dantiston: If I print V[M], then it simply prints the value of V[0], V[1] etc. There is no problem. The problem is becoming strange now.

Comment: @TanmoyChakraborty showing the print out of your variable can be very helpful, because that can oftentimes show the error (like in this case) (I'm learning how to best post to stackoverflow too!) Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list `V` is a list of *strings*.  You must convert these values to floating point numbers before passing them to `np.interp`.

You could change this:

```
        V.append(parts[1])
```

to this:

```
        V.append(float(parts[1]))
```

Comment: Many many thanks Warren for the correct solution. It's working now. Thanks!!